# How to create shadows of buildings with r.sunmask?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, shell, shadow

I need to create image-raster with shadow of relief and shadow of buildings in one. I know how to create shadow of relief but how i can create shadow of buildings with r.sunmask? I dont know how from 2D polygon layer of buildings create shadow of complete buildings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run [r.sun](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.sun.html), not r.sunmask for this task. There are also convenient [GRASS GIS addons](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/) to run it in hourly or daily mode.

You first need to extrude your buildings with [v.extrude](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.extrude.html), then run the solar computation. See for extrusion "[Extrude 2D polygons to 3D](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Extrude_2D_polygons_to_3D)" and for a shadow example [here](https://ncsu-osgeorel.github.io/grass-temporal-workshop/#visualization-of-solar-radiation).

[image]

*(image courtesy: Markus Neteler)*

[image]

*(image courtesy: [Vaclav Petras](https://plus.google.com/+V%C3%A1clavPetr%C3%A1%C5%A1/posts/X1bXZFCMCXF))*

Comment: Hi, does this take the topography into account for computing the shade?

Comment: Yes it does. Above surface includes the topography and the buildings, put together (I am not the author).

Comment: Thanks for answergin @markusN

Comment: I can't install r.sun.hourly, can you help me here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/471645/install-grass-missing-addons-within-qgis ? thank you