# Install GRASS missing addons within QGIS

Tags: grass-gis

I'd like to use `r.sun.hourly` and `r.sun.daily` from within QGIS but it doesn't seem to be present in GRASS tools.
I tried to install it using g.extension in the GRASS shell, but it says I have to run it with sudo, and sudo g.extension gives command not found.

I have QGIS 3.26, GRASS 7.8.2  Ubuntu 20.04.

Nota: `r.sun` is not even present in my installation...

**EDIT** I tried to open the GRASS shell and use the g.extension command like this :

```
$ g.extension r.sun
```

I get :

```
GRASS_ADDON_BASE is not defined
```

so I tried to define it :

[image]

and

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Note that GRASS GIS commands like `g.extension` need to be run in a GRASS GIS session. You can either define environmental variables or simply use the `--exec` method, see https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/grass.html#batch-jobs-with-the-exec-interface.  This will set all needed paths as well.